# please help me solve this error in c programming

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
int main()
{
    char c,a;
    FILE *fptr,*fp2;
    fptr = fopen("program.txt", "w");

    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    gets(c);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s",c);
    fclose(fptr);
    fptr = fopen("program.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("test.txt", "w");

    do
    {
        a = fgetc(fptr);
        fputc(a, fp2);
    }
    while(a != EOF);
}
```

The error is:

```
error C2664: 'gets':cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char*'
```

Comment: `char c,a;` change to `char c[128]; int a;`

Comment: also change to `while((a=fgetc(fptr))!=EOF){ fputc(a, fp2);}`

Comment: If you want to read a single  character, use [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) instead. And if you want to read a string then note that `gets` have been obseleted since the C99 standard, and removed completely in the C11 standard. Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Answer (score 1):

> error: error C2664:'gets':cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char*'

the error is quite self-explaining. All it says is that the paramater supplied for `gets()` should be a `char *` but all you supplied is of type `char`.

As per the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html), the syntax for `gets()` is

> char *gets(char *s);

so, the argument to `gets()` should be a `char *`, not a `char`.

You need to change `c` in your code to something like

```
char c[64] = {0};
```

Note: use of  `gets()` is very bad. use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) instead.

Comment: again getting error      variable c is being use without being initialised.